# How to fix "android.process.media keeps stopping" - error re-appears in a 10-second loop

Tags: internal-storage, storage, crashes, media-files, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

On a Galaxy Tab A on stock ROM the last update was the June 1 2022 patch for Android 10 received from Samsung in Oct 2022 and also brought with it some Samsung updates.  The update has introduced a serious error for me.  When the tablet boots and whenever I access a file (e.g. when I save a file from the web browser) I receive the error

```
android.process.media keeps stopping

(i) App info
 x  Close app
```

as a popup in the lower area of the screen.  When I click "x Close App" the error immediately re-appears.  If I wait instead the error message is removed after a timeout of 10 seconds and then also immediately re-appears.

Often, though after a few minutes the error message disappears.  Clicking the "x Close App" a few dozen times will apparently not accelerate the end of the error loop, however.  The next time internal or SD card storage is accessed by an app the error loop will start again.

**How can I make this error disappear for good?**  May I try to disable android.process.media?  I mean **what does it do, do I need it?**  What is the connection to Sec(ure) Media Storage?  I used to have errors about Sec Media Storage, too but they have disappeared somehow.

I have used the tablet for a few years and I have many files on it that I do not want to lose.  So, any fix or suggestion **may not include a data wipe or reset of the tablet**.  I cannot move files from Internal to SD Card storage - the file manager will just crash and the error message appear.  MTP is also dysfunctional and no connection to the computer is possible.

I have disabled lots of pre-installed apps I do not need or use but no new one when the error appeared.

**EDIT 1:**

Following the recommendation by mmmatey I went through all items in their list of steps to perform.  Here are the results:

- Deleted the `Google Play Store` Cache (Data cannot be deleted)
- I cannot `Reset App Preferences` because it would literally take hours to re-set everything (also, none of these settings were changed when the system first appeared so it is perhaps not likely to help)
- There is no `Contacts` app but I cleared the Cache of `Contacts Storage` (again, Data cannot be cleared)
- I tried disabling `Media Storage` but it cannot be disabled
- There is no `Google Sync` option in Settings so I could not change anything here
- `Media Storage` holds the photos on the device so I won't be able to clear it without losing data I still need.

Afterwards, I rebooted the tablet.  **No change, sadly.**

Digging through these options and setting shows to me again how many unneeded apps Samsung pre-installs.  Also many unused items cannot be disabled and other things are locked.  One would at least hope that then "everything works" because the user cannot change an important setting but this is clearly not always the case.

Comment: The solution might be to clear the cache for Google Play services and Application Manager app, check on this link with provided steps: https://appuals.com/android-process-media-has-stopped/